# Set up Git over different geographical regions

Tags: git

We would like to setup on main Git server in one country and have a cached/proxy server in another country. We work with huge file sizes so to reduce time to checkin and checkouts we would like to go with this approach.

How can we set up the cached/proxy Git server?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the idea of a mirror, like in this article "[Setting up backup (mirror) repositories on GitHub](https://wincent.com/wiki/Setting_up_backup_%28mirror%29_repositories_on_GitHub)".

In your case, you wouldn't use GitHub for your mirror, but you would setup a cron job which make sure your secondary server git repo is in sync with your first server, executing a do_push for all your repos.

```
do_push()
{
  for REPO in $1/*.git; do
    (cd $REPO && git push github)
  done
}
```

Comment: I an not sure if this will help. The above approach will only work if it is a backup repository. I think we will run into problems when files are modified and checked in directly into the main server. the cron job will fail. I am looking for something that would keep syncing both main git server and seconday git server both ways.

Comment: @kumar why would it be problematic when "files are modified and checked in directly into the main server"? You only sync from the main to the secondary, right?

Comment: Consider this example File1-MainRepository-Country1 and File1-SecondayRepository-Country2. If a person from Country1 changes File1 and checks it into Main Repository. then a person from Country2 check in same file File1 into Seconday Repository. So when secondary sync's to the main using a cron job there will be a conflict. I am looking for something syncing both ways.